# Logic question involving prime numbers

Tags: logic

Explain why the statement,“$n^2 + 4n + 3$ is a prime” is not true for any integer $n ≥ 1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$n^2+4n+3 = (n+1)(n+3)$, hence the conclusion.

Comment: ... and because of $n\ge1$ both factors are $\ge2$ - to be precise :-)